# Schedule next run time is incorrect

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, jboss, wildfly

I have a simple Schedule like below which should run every 30 minutes from 6pm to 10:30pm.

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Schedules;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class XxxJob {

  @Schedules({
    @Schedule(minute = "0,30", hour = "18-22", dayOfWeek = "Mon-Fri",
              timezone = "Europe/London", persistent = false)
  })
  public void process() {
    //...
  }
}
```

But when I check the details of the timer on the Wildfly console, I see this:

> {"time-remaining" => 30039141L,"next-timeout" => 1498757400000L,"calendar-timer" => true,"persistent" => false,"schedule" => {"year" => "*","month" => "*","day-of-month" => "*","day-of-week" => "Mon-Fri","hour" => "18-22","minute" => "0,30","second" => "0","timezone" => "Europe/London","start" => undefined,"end" => undefined}}

It says the next run (next-timeout) is at `1498757400000L` (epoch millis) but that corresponds to `2017-06-29T18:30+01:00[Europe/London]` and not 18:00.

**Why is the timer scheduled to run at 18:30 and not at 18:00?**

---

Note 1: if I amend the schedule to only run at 18:00 it works as expected:

```
@Schedule(minute = "0", hour = "18", dayOfWeek = "Mon-Fri",
          timezone = "Europe/London", persistent = false)
```

Note 2: if I remove the `@Schedules` annotation it works as expected too.

Comment: My question: Do you have any issues at all or have you resolved your issue?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi In my real application, I have several schedules and therefore need the `@Schedules` annotation and the "notes" at the bottom don't help. The example in the question is simpler than reality but reproduces the problem.